# Error: symbol `pread64' is already defined

Tags: ruby, gcc, libc

I am trying to compile ruby-2.2.3. I have downloaded the package and configured it. But when I tried to make it, It is throwing the following error:

```
compiling main.c
/tmp/cc2lrvgn.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc2lrvgn.s:413: Error: symbol `pread64' is already defined
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Following are my system details :

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
Release:        5.10
Codename:       Final
```

Following is the version details of compiler that I am using:

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I have done some investigation about this error and found that this bug is present in libc-
headers. I tried to upgrade libc-headers. But that also didn't help. So if anyone have solved this problem, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's triggered by a change in gcc 4.3 that causes it to be incompatible with older glibc headers:
http://lifecs.likai.org/2009/06/multiple-definition-of-extern-inline.html
from that article, a quick work around is to add -fgnu89-inline to your CFLAGS:

./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ruby-2.2.3 ... CFLAGS=-fgnu89-inline

and then make should work.